# margin-bottom doesn't work in this case

Tags: html, css

The code below shows two links in the div with a small width.

```
<style>
div{
width: 89.5px;
border:1px solid #ddd;
}

a{
  border:1px solid red;
  display: inline;

  margin-bottom:30px;
}
</style>
<div>
<a href="#">AAAAAAA</a>
<a href="#">BBBBBBBB</a>
</div>
```

Any ideas why `margin-bottom:30px;` doesn't work so that one button would be below another one for about 30px?

What's the best way to **slightly** modify this code so there is a gap between buttons?

And here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oquuy0vb/1) if needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inline elements can't have margins.

If you need to add to link margin, you need to make this link `block`, or `inline-block`. You need the `inline-block` here.

```
a {display: inline-block}
```

When you set there `block`, margin will be apllied and link width will be 100% (or better, `100% - side margins - paddings - borders`).

Note: you set `display: inline`, which do nothing in this case. Links are `inline` by default.

Comment: `inline-block` is better if you want to keep the "not full width" thing that `inline` gives you, while being able to use the margins that only `block`s can have.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I've updated my answer, when you wrote the comment, I've just finished my update. But, thanks :-)

Comment: BTW, inline boxes can have horizontal margins, but not vertical

Answer (score 2):

I see the issue and it is because you are using display:inline as opposed to display:block.

```
a{
  border:1px solid red;
  display: block;

  margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

Comment: There is different behavior between `block` and `inline-block`. `Inline-block` is better in this case. OP declared `display: inline` which means _set width as text is wide, not 100%_.